# Building a pyramid and outputting the first line

Tags: java

Based on the code below I am trying to print out a pyramid using any input of rows that looks like this:

```
      *
     *o*
    *o*o*
```

but with an arbitrary amount of rows. Everything lines up correctly but I cant figure out how to get the first star to correctly line up. Currently it outputs something like this with rows being 5:

```
              *
            *o*
         *o *o *o*
      *o *o *o *o *o*
   *o *o *o *o *o *o *o*
*o *o *o *o *o *o *o *o *o*
```

My code :

```
System.out.println("Please enter a number of rows: ");
                    int row = scan.nextInt();//takes in number of rows 
                    in=scan.nextLine(); //gets rid of error with .nextInt();                    
                    String s="*";
                    String pat="o";
                    if(row>1){//this will only run through if the number of rows entered is greater than 1

                        for (int i =0; i <= row; i++) {//this for loop is used to build the pyramid pattern
                            // for spacing
                           for (int j = 1; j <= row - i; j++){             
                                System.out.print("   ");      
                            }

                            // left half of the pyramid           
                            for (int k = i; k >= 1; k--){
                                if(k==0){

                                    System.out.println(s);
                                }else{
                                System.out.print((k >= row+1) ? + k: " "+s + pat);
                                }
                            }
                            // corresponding right half of the pyramid
                            for (int k = 2; k <= i; k++) {                                  
                                System.out.print((k >= row+1) ? +k :  " "+ s + pat);
                            }
                            // next line
                            System.out.println("*");
                            }

                    }else{
                        System.out.println(s);
                    }
```

Comment: You are concatenating a space to s and pat (`" " + s + pat`) - are you surprised that `" *o"` appears in the output?

Comment: @AndyTurner has the answer. By the way, there is no good reason to differentiate the left and right parts of the pyramid : this is the exact same pattern, and should be handled is the exact same loop

Comment: @AndyTurner I am not surprised that is the output. apologies if it was unclear but I was trying to get the first line to line up correctly in the middle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is a row? It's zero or more spaces followed by a `*` followed by `n` repeats of `o*` for `n`=0,1,2,... Then advance to the next line.

Translate this into Java, ignoring spaces for now:

```
static void printRowVisiblePart(int n) {
  System.out.print("*");
  for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    System.out.print("o*");
  }
  System.out.println();  
}
```

Just for fun, let's use this to print out only the visible part of the pyramid of height `k`:

```
public class PyramidPrinter {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    int k = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
    for (int n = 0; n < k; n++) {
      printRowVisiblePart(n);
    }
  }

  private static void printRowVisiblePart(int n) {
    System.out.print("*");
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
      System.out.print("o*");
    }
    System.out.println();  
  }
}
```

We get:

```
*
*o*
*o*o*
*o*o*o*
*o*o*o*o*
```

This is close.  We need some spaces at the start of each line.

How many? Start by writing a little method to print them:

```
static void printSpaces(int n) {
  for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    System.out.print(' ');
  }
}
```

There are fancier ways, but this is fine.

Now work backward. For the last row we have `n` = `k-1` where `k` is read from the user. We know that in this row we need zero spaces. Inspecting your picture, note each row has one more space than its successor. For row zero, then, we need `k-1` spaces, counting down for each successive row so we get to zero at row `k-1`.  In row `n`, we need `k - 1 - n` spaces. So change `main` a bit to print these spaces before each visible part of the line.

```
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    int k = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
    for (int n = 0; n < k; n++) {
      printSpaces(k - 1 - n); // k-1 at n=0 and 0 at n=k-1!
      printRowVisiblePart(n);
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I would start by splitting the problem into smaller more manageable pieces. First, ignore scanner and input data until the solution works as you want.

Make a simple program that prints multiple pyramids at once so you can quickly verify that they all work after making a change.

I would choose to split it down to functions returning Strings. For instance I make a method 'getRow' that returns a String containing each row.

All you really need to create a row is the height of the pyramid and the current row index.

Generally, by splitting problems you can focus on one task at a time until you are certain that that part is working.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    printPyramid(1);
    System.out.println("----------------------");
    printPyramid(2);
    System.out.println("----------------------");
    printPyramid(3);
    System.out.println("----------------------");
    printPyramid(4);
    System.out.println("----------------------");
    printPyramid(5);
    System.out.println("----------------------");
}

private static void printPyramid(int height) {
    String pyramid = getPyramid(height);
    System.out.print(pyramid);
}

private static String getPyramid(int height) {
    String pyramid = "";
    for (int i = 1; i <= height; i++) {
        String row = getRow(height, i);
        pyramid += (row + System.lineSeparator());
    }
    return pyramid;
}

private static String getRow(int height, int row) {
    // Put all the pieces together
}

private static String getMargin(int size) {
    // return as many spaces as size
}

private static String getBody(int widthForThisRow) {
    // All bodies are the same, the question is how large they are, use widthForThisRow in a loop and see if the index is divisible by 2.
}
```